# Keybinding for Format Code -> Shift+Alt+F in VS Code does not seem to work

Tags: .net, xml, format, visual-studio-code

On this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings#_rich-languages-editing) the following keybinding is described:

[image]

What I need is the ability to load an XML and have it properly formatted, as you would with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> +<kbd>D</kbd> in visual studio.

I had prepared this xml content:

```
<root><level1><sublevel1A></sublevel1A><sublevel1B></sublevel1B></level1><level2><sublevel2A></sublevel2A></level2></root>
```

Which would need to be formatted to this:

```
<root>
    <level1>
        <sublevel1A>
        </sublevel1A>
        <sublevel1B>
        </sublevel1B>
    </level1>
    <level2>
        <sublevel2A>
        </sublevel2A>
    </level2>
</root>
```

Nothing happens though if I use the key binding. Nor does it help if I select everything first.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in support for XML formatting in VSCode. To get XML formatting you need install this extension - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabianlauer.vs-code-xml-format

---

Also, you have a typo in your example XML, `</subleve1B>` instead of `</sublevel1B>`

Comment: It looks like this could work, but I get a timeout, possibly my firewall blocks the request?

Answer (score 1):

The [XML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-xml) extension from Red Hat provides, among many other features, formatting support for XML document:[image: Formatting XML]

It requires a JDK >= 8 to run.